# refresh view after changing json data binded Angular 2+

Tags: json, angular, page-refresh

So, the case is the following (i'm going to simplify the code so it's more readable but the same case, i'm using json-server to mount a localhost with the Json file):

i have a json file in a url (say "http://localhost:3000")with information like this:

```
{
  "Object1":{
    "a":"Lorem ipsum",
    "b":"Dolor sit"},

  "Object2":{
    "a":"Amet Consectetur",
    "b":"Adipiscing elit"}
}
```

and a service to get this data, with a method that changes the objet of the json to get the data from

getData.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class GetDataService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  private jsonURL: string = "http://localhost:3000/Object1"

  getData() {

      return (this.http.get(this.jsonURL).map((response:Response)=>response.json()))
  }

}

  changeData(param) {
      if (param = 'Obj1'){
      this.jsonURL = "http://localhost:3000/Object1"
      }this.jsonURL = "http://localhost:3000/Object2"        
  }

}
```

and a component with a function that calls the function of the service, like this one

component1.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetDataService } from './services/getData.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {

  data = [] 

  constructor(private getDataService: GetDataService,
              ) { }

  changeData(param) {

  this.getDataService.changeData(param)
  }

 ngOnInit() {

    const  GetDataService  = this.getDataService.getData().subscribe(data => this.data= data);

  }
```

and an html template with the property "a" of the "Objetc1" binded, and two buttons that call the function of the getDataService to change the object of the json where i bind the data from:

component1.component.hml:

```
<p>{{data.a}}</p>
<button (click)="changeData('Obj1')">This button changes the url to Object1</button>
<button (click)="changeData('Obj2')">This button changes the url to Object2</button>
```

the case is that the url is actually changed (i made a console.log() of the jsonURL variable of the service and it does change, but the view is not refreshed after that change and the {{data.a}} points to the "a" property of Object1 and not to the proerty "a" of the Object2, even when the url points to the Object2.

is there a way to refresh the view after making that change?

Comment: Seems you are only changing a URL when a button click happens. You are not trying to `get` any data afterward. Or, is there something missing from this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**getData.service.ts:**

```
...
getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.jsonURL).map(response => response.json());
}

changeData(param) {
    if (param = 'Obj1') this.jsonURL = "http://localhost:3000/Object1";
    else this.jsonURL = "http://localhost:3000/Object2";

    return this.getData();
}
...
```

**component1.component.ts:**

```
...
data = [] 

constructor(private getDataService: GetDataService) { }

changeData(param) {
    this.getDataService.changeData(param).subscribe(res => this.data = data);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataService.getData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
...
```